# how to dynamically set drawer items based on authentication in react-navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

i want to set items dynamically in drawer based on login status.
When any user login into application, then some extra drawer items like change password,Inquiry or etc to be shown. Login is not mandatory for app and i have used contentComponent to generate the drawer items.